# Jquery Flexigrid text-align

Tags: flexigrid, text-align

Im using simple solution (example 1) of Flexigrid

http://www.flexigrid.info/

What I'm trying to do is to align text in one of the columns to the right.
Is there a way to do this without connecting to a JSON file (example 3)?

Answer (score 6):

Use the colModel and set that column to have align: 'right'.   Take a look at the last example on the page you linked for the syntax.

```
 colModel: [ 
         { display: 'Col1', name: 'Col1' },
         ...
         { display: 'Col4',  name: 'Col4', align: 'right' }
 ]
```